# Capture the last value from a ´yield from´ expression

Tags: python

Let's assume we want to have a generator that is recursively yielding values and, as a convenience, we have a sub-iterator that we yield from.

```
def gen(l, last_value=0):

    if not l:
        return None

    yield from (l[0] + i + last_value for i in range(3))
    yield from gen(l[1:])
```

How can we capture the last returned value from the sub-iterator, so that we can feed it to the second one?

Is this even possible?

Here is a possible solution, that drops the use of the yield from:

```
def gen(l, last_value=0):

    if not l:
        return None

    for x in (l[0] + i + last_value for i in range(3)):
        yield x

    yield from gen(l[1:], x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we are aware of sub-iterator's length in this case, we can slice it using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) till the second last item and then fetch the last item by simply calling `next()` on the remaining slice.

Using `islice` you prevent a Python level for-loop:

```
from itertools import islice

def gen(l, last_value=0):

    if not l:
        return None

    it = (l[0] + i + last_value for i in range(3))
    yield from islice(it, 2)
    last = next(it)
    yield last
    yield from gen(l[1:], last)
```

---

Another way, but something that defeats the purpose of using an iterator is using the [extended variable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

```
it = (l[0] + i + last_value for i in range(3))
*items, last = it # Now items is a tuple
yield from items
yield last
yield from gen(l[1:], last)
```

Comment: If we have control ove the  sub-iterator we can return a value once it is exhausted. Which can work in cases where you have control over the sub-iterator.

`extended variable unpacking` can't believe I did not know of the existence of such a feature. Thanks!